# If $A = R R^T$, prove that $||R_1 R_1^T||_2 \le ||A||_2$ where $R_1$ is first column of $R$.

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, svd, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> For $A$ positive definite, let the Cholesky factorization be $A = R R^T$. Prove that $$\|R\|_2 \le \sqrt{\|A\|_2}$$ and that the vector $2$-norm of $R_1 R_1^T$ will never be greater than $\|A\|_2$ where $R_i$ is the $i$-th column of $R$.

---

Here, the matrix $2$-norm is defined as

$$\|A\|_2 := \max_{\|x\|_2 = 1} \|Ax\|_2$$

For the first bit, expanding $R^T = U_R \Sigma_R V_R^T$ via a singular value decomposition gives that in fact $\|R\|_2 = \sqrt{\| A \|_2}$, as $\Sigma_R^2 = \Sigma_A$. But I am unsure how to prove that $2$-norm of $R_1 R_1^T$ will never be greater than $\|A\|_2$. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: The hint was to use Courant-Fisher theorem or Weil's inequality, but I couldn't progress any further with this as well.

Comment: As stated, your inequality is impossible; it is easy to see that $\|R_1R_1^T\| \leq \sqrt{\|A\|_2}$ fails for $1 \times 1$ matrices. I suspect the intended result is either $\|R_1\|_2 \leq \sqrt{\|A\|_2}$ or $\|R_1R_1^T\|_2 \leq \|A\|_2$ (these two inequalities are logically equivalent).

Comment: @BenGrossmann, my goodness-you're right!! I must have copied this exercise down wrong in my lecture notes. Would you have any intuition as to what the correct inequality might be? (Edit: I fixed it the only way it made sense)

Comment: $\|R_1R_1^T\|_2=\|R_1\|_2^2=\|Re_1\|_2^2\le\|R\|_2^2=\|A\|_2$.

Comment: @user1551 yes, I noticed that too--the original problem was wrong and it was edited to be correct, so now there is that simple solution. But right now I'm trying to use Weil's inequality (typed out in a comment below to the hint given by Ben) to try to solve the problem.

Comment: @user1551 wait, actually, why is $||R_1R_1^T||_2 = ||R_1||_2^2$? This wasn't as immediate as I thought it was.

Comment: When $u$ and $v$ are two nonzero vectors, $(u/\|u\|_2)(\|u\|_2\|v\|_2)(v^T/\|v\|_2)$ is an economic SVD of $uv^T$. Therefore $\|uv^T\|_2=\|u\|_2\|v\|_2$. Alternatively, the operator norm definition of $\|\cdot\|_2$ also gives $\|uv^T\|_2=\|u\|_2\|v\|_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** There's no need to invoke the SVD here. Note that
$$
A = RR^T = \sum_{i=1}^n R_iR_i^T
$$
is a sum of positive semidefinite matrices. If $A,B$ are positive semidefinite, then there is an inequality relating the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ to the eigenvalues of $A + B$ that I suspect you have somewhere in your notes. If you do not, then you can deduce this inequality using the fact that for symmetric matrices $M$,
$$
\lambda_{\max}(M) = \max_{\|x\| = 1} x^TMx.
$$

---

To elaborate, we have the following.

$$
\lambda_{\max}(A + B) = \max_{\|x\| = 1} x^T(A + B)x 
= \max_{\|x\| = 1}(x^TAx + x^TBx) 
\\ \geq \max_{\|x\| = 1} (x^TAx + 0) = \lambda_{\max}(A).
$$
From there, set $A = R_1R_1^T$ and $B = \sum_{i=2}^n R_iR_i^T$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! (+1) I was trying to use $||A+B||_2 \in ||A||_2 +[-||B||_2,||B||_2]$. I want to let $A = R_1R_1^T$, and $B=\sum_{i=2}^n R_i R_i^T$. But I can't see how this inequality can help me prove something in the form of $||\cdot|| \le ||\cdot||$ which can help in this situation. Could you help me a bit more understanding this?

Comment: @Clarent See my edit. Regarding your comment on the question, this is *not* using the full power of Weyl's inequalities.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. However, I am still unsure how this proves $||R_1R_1^T||_2 \le ||\sum_{i=1}^n R_iR_i^T||_2$. Haven't we just written that $||\sum_{i=1}^n R_iR_i^T||_2 \le ||R_1R_1^T||_2 + ||\sum_{i=2}^n R_iR_i^T||_2$? I don't understand how $||R_1R_1^T||_2 \le ||\sum_{i=1}^n R_iR_i^T||_2$ follows, I must be missing something very simple.

Comment: @Clarent Sorry, you're right, I made a silly mistake there. My latest edit is what I initially had in mind.